# undefined method `empty?' for #<PG::Result:0x007fcc82900a78>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite

We migrated our database from sqlite3 to postgreSQL. Now, at the following line, we get an error:

```
  def self.get_table_id(id)
    sql = "SELECT id FROM configtables WHERE parent = 'check' AND parentid = " + id.to_s
    results = connection.execute(sql)
    return nil if results.empty? # here's where the error happens
    return results[0][0]
  end
```

I have less knowledge of Ruby and ActiveRecords and with postgreSQL as well. Is the value in `results` a `postgres-object`, or whats `#<PG::Result:0x007fcc82900a78>` and what was it with the `sqlite3` database?

This function is one of a few with raw sql-strings.

Comment: Try `results = connection.execute(sql).to_a`

Comment: Or use `select_all` instead of `execute` which results in a `ActiveRecord::Result`. You can then call [these methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html)

Comment: @radubogdan Thank you, this works as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty?` is not defined for `PG::Result`:

```
PG::Result.instance_methods.include?(:empty?)
#=> false
```

To use `empty?` you should convert the result to an instance of Array:

```
results.to_a.empty?
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. With the `sqlite` database I get a `hash`, with `postgreSQL` this `PG::Result`-object. Is this only because it's a raw SQL-query or why is this different?

Comment: @llqadude of course for pure ActiveRecord queries you will alway get instance of particular model. However actual work with database is done by gems 'pg' and 'sqlite3' respectively. For a plain query (like yours in the OP) sqlite3 will run [this](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/v1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L152) method (which will give you an array) and pg will run [this](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/ext/pg_connection.c#L3196) (which will give you `PG::Result`)

Comment: shooot, I missed the comment yesterday :\ Thanks @Aleksey for answering it!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko not at all. I am not sure if I answer it right but it seems to be so =)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you should "fetch" actual results from `PG::Result` object.
One way of doing this could be calling `to_a`

Try the following:

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM configtables WHERE parent = 'check' AND parentid = " + id.to_s
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I posted a follow-up question to this on Andrey Deineko's answer.